# Docker: Failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, build, debian

I have been trying make gitlab CI/CD pipelines to build and push deb package on servers. I have been referring this article https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/10/12/automated-debian-package-build-with-gitlab-ci/

but when running command

```
docker build -t generic-package-build-runner:v1
```

I am getting this error:

```
[+] Building 2.0s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:wheezy                                                         1.9s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:wheezy:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:2259b099d947443e44bbd1c94967c785361af8fd22df48a08a3942e2d5630849: not found
```

Although it is not mentioned  in the article to make a docker-compose.yml, but I still tried doing with that, but it gives me

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                             
unable to prepare context: path "/Users/it340/MyFolder/DebPackageGitLabDocker/Dockerfile" not found
```

Here is my code:

setup.sh

```
# change to our own mirror
echo "deb http://pkg.adfinis-sygroup.ch/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list  
echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list  
echo "deb http://pkg.adfinis-sygroup.ch/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# requirements
apt-get update  
apt-get -y install git dh-make build-essential autoconf autotools-dev
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  gitcicd:
    build: Dockerfile
```

DockerFile

```
FROM debian:wheezy 
ADD  setup.sh /opt/  
RUN  /bin/bash setup.sh
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?